# Proper code for a For Loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is this proper code for javascript?

```
var inputsClass = document.getElementsByClassName("inputClass");
var errorSpan = document.getElementsByClassName("errorSpan");

for(var index=0; index < inputsClass.length;index++ ){

    inputsClass[index].onclick=function(){

    inputsClass[index].errorSpan.style.color="black";

    }
}
```

Because in my JavaScript console it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined` But I have an equal amount of tags that have the class `inputsClass` and `errorSpan`. Yet `inputsClass[index]` seems undefined.

HTML Portion

```
    <h1> SIGN UP </h1>
<br />
<input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name"        
    class="inputClass" autofocus/>
<span class="errorSpan"> Testing... </span>
<br />
<input type="text" name="lastName"  placeholder="Last Name" class="inputClass"/>
<span class="errorSpan"> Testing... </span>
<br />
<input type="text" name="userName"  placeholder="Username" class="inputClass"/>
<span class="errorSpan"> Testing... </span>
<br />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="inputClass"/>
<span class="errorSpan"> Testing... </span>
<br />
<input type="password" name="retypePassword" placeholder="Retype Password"       
    class="inputClass"/>
<span class="errorSpan"> Testing... </span>
<br />
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="inputClass"/>
<span class="errorSpan"> Testing... </span>
<br />
```

So the testing text node should turn black when the input tags are clicked on.
By the way, I really appreciate you helping me out jfriend00

Comment: Your `var` declares nothing.  There is no variable attached to the elements you are getting.

Comment: You may not use `var` as a variable name, it's a reserved word in JavaScript.

Comment: Even though your code is incomplete, I assume it's the typical closure in the loop problem. At least the error message suggests so.

Comment: Not only that, but the inputs do not have a `.errorSpan` property as well.

Comment: @Bergi: True, but if that was actually the OP's code, he should get the error "Cannot read property errorSpan of undefined". But who knows... that's the problem with incomplete code...

Comment: If you show your actual HTML and explain what you are trying to accomplish rather than just post a piece of code that doesn't work, we can offer more complete advice.

Comment: Folks, this question has a closure in a loop issue, but it also has another issue in that `errorSpan` isn't a property of the `inputsClass` so this is NOT a pure duplicate of what it's been marked a dup of and reading that other question and it's answers will not solve the OP's problem (which should be the actual definition of a duplicate).  I voted to reopen based on the fact that this question has more issues than just a missing closure.

Comment: I was trying to add a functionality where each click of an input tag would change following span tags' color to black. For example, a click on input1 would change the color or span1, and a click on input2 would change the color or span2. I thought looping through would assign each input an onclick event and also change the span tag colors when clicked on

Comment: @user3029001 - as I've said twice now, show us your HTML and we can help you much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple issues.  The first issue is that your `onclick` handler function is called sometime LATER, long after your `for` loop has finished.  That means that the value of your loop variable `index` is going to be at the end of the sequence and not valid inside the event handler function.

You can fix the first issue by adding a closure that captures the index value separately for each callback function.

The second issue is that you can't do `inputsClass[i].errorSpan`.  `errorSpan` isn't a valid property of `inputsClass[i]`.

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do with the `errorSpan`.  If you want to find the errorSpan that is contained within the particular `inputClass` object, then you would do `inputClass[i].getElementsByClassname("errorSpan")[0]`.  If `inputClass` and `errorSpan` are parallel arrays and from the `i` inputClass, you want to refer to the `i` `errorSpan`, then you would do `errorSpan[i]`.  Here are the two versions:

Find `errorSpan` contained within `inputsClass`:

```
var inputsClass = document.getElementsByClassName("inputClass");

for(var index=0; index < inputsClass.length;index++ ){
    (function(i) {
        inputsClass[i].onclick = function() {
            inputsClass[i].getElementsByClassName("errorSpan")[0].style.color="black";
        }
    })(index);
}
```

Use parallel arrays of `inputsClass` and `errorSpan`:

```
var inputsClass = document.getElementsByClassName("inputClass");
var errorSpan = document.getElementsByClassName("errorSpan");

for(var index=0; index < inputsClass.length;index++ ){
    (function(i) {
        inputsClass[i].onclick = function() {
            errorSpan[i].style.color="black";
        }
    })(index);
}
```

If you show your actual HTML and explain what you are trying to accomplish rather than just post a piece of code that doesn't work, we can offer more complete advice.